# how to get the position of an Image object

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, awt

i'm working on a vertical scrolling game, to create hit detection / collision i decided to ripoff the intersects method from the Rectangle class:

```
public boolean intersects(Rectangle r){
  return r.width > 0 && r.height > 0 && width > 0 && height > 0
   && r.x < x + width && r.x + r.width > x
   && r.y < y + height && r.y + r.height > y; }
```

And changing all of the "internal components" of this method with Image methods.
The problem is, there is no method in the Image Class that returns the position of an image object on jpanel like ".getX()". I tried to create a separate Rectangle object for each Image on the screen and use it as a hitbox, but this seems a bit wasteful, and i run out ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This was something I did a long time ago](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/444547/game-development-loop-logic-and-collision-detection-java-swing-2d):

Essentially for your `GameObject`s you should have a class which encapsulates the image for the `GameObject` and its data (i.e. *X*, *Y*, *height* and *width* etc.) , this class should have a `Rectangle2D` associated with it and any movement on this `GameObject` should in fact move the `Rectangle2D` associated with them see some extracted code below:

```
class GameObject extends Animator {

    protected Rectangle2D.Double rectangle;

    public GameObject(int x, int y, ArrayList<BufferedImage> frames, ArrayList<Long> timings, int pos, int conW, int conH) {
        super(frames, timings);
        //...
        // I have a list of images thats set in the Animator class but if you had one image you would have the setter for it here and it would be passed into the constructor and this GameObject would have a getCurrentImage or similar method which returns the BufferedImage associated with the GameObject.
        rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, getCurrentImage().getWidth(), getCurrentImage().getHeight());
        //...
    }

    public void setX(double x) {
        rectangle.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(double y) {
        rectangle.y = y;
    }

    public void setWidth(double width) {
        rectangle.width = width;
    }

    public void setHeight(double height) {
        rectangle.height = height;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return rectangle.x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return rectangle.y;
    }

    public double getWidth() {
        if (getCurrentImage() == null) {//there might be no image (which is unwanted ofcourse but  we must not get NPE so we check for null and return 0
            return rectangle.width = 0;
        }

        return rectangle.width = getCurrentImage().getWidth();
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        if (getCurrentImage() == null) {
            return rectangle.height = 0;
        }
        return rectangle.height = getCurrentImage().getHeight();
    }

    public Rectangle2D getBounds2D() {
        return rectangle.getBounds2D();
    }

    public boolean intersects(GameObject go) {
        return rectangle.intersects(go.getBounds2D());
    }
}
```

Then you simply draw your `GameObject`  using the below logic (you get the image for the `GameObject` and the *X* and *Y* co-ordinates of its associated *rectangle*):

```
g2d.drawImage(gameObject.getCurrentImage(), (int) gameObject.getX(), (int) gameObject.getY(), null);
```

You can then use `Rectangle2D`s:

```
rectangle.getBounds2D();
```

Which will return a `Rectangle2D` and with that you can simply call the built in `Rectangle2D#intersects` method ( see `getBounds2D` and `intersects(GameObject go)` of the above `GameObject` class) i.e.:

```
gameObject.intersects(anotherGameObject)
```